# How to remove wheel from boot

Tags: wheels, trunk

[image]Trying to remove wheel from boot but doesn't move.  From pic seems to be screwed down somehow through center hole.  Do I need a tool to twist this or something.  How can I remove the wheel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, twist that. Counterclockwise.

It's a long T bolt that secures the spare tire and keeps it from shifting around.

It may be very tight, and perhaps a bit rusty (given the corrosion on the rim).  You may need "channellock" style pliers to get it started.

You would be prudent to put some anti-seize or grease on the threads before putting it back.

You might also find that the tire is "stuck" to the floorpan of the trunk; you may need a stick or prybar to break it free.

Good news is you'll find all sorts of great stuff underneath the spare - old coins, dirt, rust, gunk, dead bugs, a bolt or two, that can of Underwood's Deviled Ham you swore you bought at the grocer seven years ago . . .

On Edit:  Sorry, I meant " . . .*tyre* stuck to the floorpan of the *boot*".  I got lazy and forgot to translate.  Apologies.